# parsing simple xml with jquery

Tags: jquery, xml

i've got a simple xml file (called by ajax) that contains only:

```
<result>1</result>
```

with jquery, i can get the value (1) of result?

thanks!
Rob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
jQuery.get('myxml.xml', function(xml){
    var result = jQuery(xml).text();
    alert(result);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/foo.xml',
    success: function(xml) {
        alert($(xml).find('result').text());
    }
});
```